# jquery - Hide a parent div , from loaded page

Tags: jquery, html, load, hide, parent-child

So ,I need to close a div from the main page , with a button from loaded page.

This is main page:

```
<div id="DIV1" style="display:none;"></div>
<div id="ShowPage1">Show 1</div>
<div id="ShowPage2">Show 2</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#ShowPage1').click(function(){
   $("#DIV1").load("test1.html");
   $("#DIV1").show();
   return false;
});
$('#ShowPage2').click(function(){
   $("#DIV1").load("test2.html");
   $("#DIV1").show();
   return false;
});
</script>
```

This is test1.html

```
<div id="HideDIV1">HideDiv</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#HideDIV1').click(function(){
   $("#DIV1").hide();
   return false;
});
</script>
```

First part , work perfectly , it load test1.html and show DIV1.
Bun when i try to hide it from test1.html #HideDIV1 , ... just don`t work.

Help please.

Comment: Is the javascript from test1.html actually running? try putting an alert() or console.log() in it to check it out.

Comment: Yes , with alert() work

Comment: Try `$('#HideDIV1').on('click', function (){ $('#DIV1').hide(); return false; });`

Comment: no , it`s not working

Comment: If i put everything in main page , after DIV1 , when i press the #HideDiv1 it work , but if #HiveDiv1 it`s in the loaded page test1.html , it not work

Comment: What if you put full URL to your test1.html page in main page? Like this 'http://host.you.use/test1.html' ?

Comment: Nothing. Didn't even load it if i use the full URL , i don't know why , but it not load it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try delegating the click event of `hideDIV1` to its parent. Let's say you append `hideDIV1` to `#DIV1`:

```
$('#DIV1').on('click','#hideDIV1',function(){
    $("#DIV1").hide();
       return false;
});
```

This would go in the script of the main page.

Comment: Sorry, missed the selector of hideDIV1. Check the updated answer (added # to the selector)